# 15.04 new monitor adds only after opening settings

Tags: multiple-monitors

I just wanted to know if devs are aware that (maybe it's only for me) if you attach new monitor it doesn't come alive until you open system settings (any part of it).
I have Ubuntu 15.04 x64
HP probook 450 g1
Intel core i5 4200m 
Radeon HD 8750m (using xorg driver (system default)

Might be that it is already posted as bug, but I couldn't find it. Or maybe there is already some workaround? Of course those 10s while I open settings ain't so much but still at one point it starts to bother.

Regards